# How to explain "edit your question instead of adding to comments" to a user?

Tags: discussion

Is there something I could have done to make myself understood by this user?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31114691/how-to-convert-dictionary-to-escaped-json-value-in-swift?noredirect=1#comment50244556_31114691

*He keeps adding information to the comments instead of editing his question, and in this case this is particularly confusing.*

I tried to explain how it works, so that he could have a chance to get better answers, but after some time I got a bit irritated and just said "I'm giving up".

Then OP posted a last comment demonstrating that they didn't understand what I was suggesting earlier.

Maybe my explanations weren't clear for this person? Do you have advice about what to say (or not) and what to do (...or not) in such case?

It is not *that* important, but it troubles me.

Comment: Use the in-line link, so type `[edit]` and it will link to the edit page, like this: [edit]

Comment: Excellent suggestion, thank you.

Comment: Oh, what they mean by "original question" is that they're just literally just copying and pasting part of their question into the comments section. That's why they won't add it to the question; it's already there. It's the part of the question in quotes.

Comment: It's weird because this seems to be a common thing among some new users: You ask them to add or fix something in their post and they respond by just repeating the question. I don't get it but I've seen it several times.

Comment: For the record, I came across a question yesterday where the OP had used a comment to add the results of a suggestion-comment.  I added a comment along the lines of "You would do better editing that into your original question" and a few hours later they had ... so at least ONE user listens!

Comment: My only input is instead of "I give up" just say something along the lines of `I'm sorry, but I do not feel like I'm the right person to help you at this time. Please [edit] the question so that other users may be more able to help. Good luck.` this comes off a lot less aggressive. Yea it takes about 10 seconds more, but only do it on questions you feel you already wasted time on that way you feel like you're pointing them in a friendly manner to the right direction.

Comment: Checked your SO rep, and it's fair game to make the edits yourself, of course (that question is deleted, so I can't tell if you tried). I realize this leaves the comments as well, but it might be more explanatory.

Comment: @BSMP Agreed. It's very common for only the first sentence of a comment to be actually read and (over-) reacted to, and the rest ignored, and it's also quite common for the question to be merely repeated instead of clarified as requested.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I have an [auto comment](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) setup that says:

```
Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)
```

Which gets rendered as:

> Please [**edit**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/298109/edit) your question with an  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

This has worked for some of the people that do that.  If it is still a problem I would just add another comment saying something along the lines of:

> The information you are providing should be included in your question and not in the comments.  Having the needed information in the comments is not helpful as someone should be able to read just your question to give you an answer.

Comment: I would add this sentence to the end of your second solution: Otherwise you may not get complete answers to your question.

Comment: I like the way your comment is formulated. Very clear. @beerwin's addition may be a nice incentive too.

Comment: @Nathan you can replace `[edit](link to OP Question edit link)` with just `[edit]`.

Comment: @tim I am showing the source to my comment. I edited my answer to show how the comment gets rendered.

Comment: Thanks everyone. It was the confirmation I needed to be sure about what to say in this case.

Comment: @beerwin I am going to leave my suggestion alone as it is just a suggestion.  You can fell free to add it to your own comments.

Comment: @NathanOliver My comment is also a suggestion _only_. I put it into a comment to your answer, as it doesn't add too much of a value as an answer. I should have addressed it to the OP instead of you. Sorry about that.

Comment: @NathanOliver: `[edit]` is a [magic link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting). You don't need the `(...)` part.

Comment: @NathanOliver What I meant was you don't need the () section, just `[edit]` will link to it. like so: [edit]

Comment: Ah i get it.  `[edit]` will link to the post it is a comment on.

Comment: at some point in recent past they switched from SSCCE to [meta-tag:mcve] (if memory serves, author of SSCCE "blessed" this move as MCVE is more tightly tweaked for SO context)

Comment: I use this general setup too, but once in a while I get a user that just restates their unclear question, in the comments. In such cases I silently move on, usually after downvoting: it will obviously be absolutely impractical for me to help them.

Comment: @gnat In my opion SSCCE makes more sense to me then MCVE.  I suppose I could edit the comment and serve up both.

Comment: @NisseEngström - Thank you very much for the link.  I was looking for this info for quite some time.

Comment: @PM77-1: You can get to the page by clicking "**help**" and "**Learn more...**" in the comment editing box.

Comment: @gnat *"author of SSCCE "blessed" this move as MCVE"*  Yep, I sure did.  IMO either work, and are good, one has the advantage of being brief, while the other goes into more detail about the process of creating an example.  At the moment, my copy paste link of... "For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)." includes them both.  :)

Comment: @andrew thanks for commenting on that.  Now all hail the hypnotoad.

Answer (score 11):

If they couldn't be bothered to read the help material the site showed them upon sign-up, downvoting and giving up is indeed the correct thing to do.

Move on and give your time to someone who can be bothered.

Comment: Sometimes people believe they are trying their hardest even if they haven't read help material. They aren't always people to give up on. If they are doing it wrong we should suggest to them at least 1 time try reading or researching a topic that is associated with the material of the question. If they then do not understand or seem to be going to a route that is not progressive then giving a downvote and walking away before anyone gets too upset is probably correct.

Comment: @CayceK: It was already suggested to them "at least 1 time". :)

Answer (score 10):

There are people who have problems, and you can help them, but they won't listen to the help you want to give them. Or, when they don't understand what you say, they respond to that by ignoring it and hoping it wasn't important. Or, when they see more than one response, they read one and ignore the others.

This isn't particular to StackOverflow. This is just people.

But the stakes aren't high on StackOverflow. If you find yourself feeling too frustrated, giving up probably *is* the right thing to do, because:

- your comments are still there. Who knows? Maybe they'll (re)read them later and "get it".
- someone else might help them
- this one question isn't saving the world; it's just one person's programming difficulties
- giving up, for you, is easy and convenient: just close the window.

But there probably was no need to actually *say* "I give up." I suggest you only engage further when you think you can make a positive difference, and you're not getting too frustrated.