# Best practice: what to do if the comment section of an answer turns into a discussion?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, etiquette

Consider my [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31144233/1141118).

After writing my answer, the OP added details related to his question as a comment. Though it would be preferable to update the question instead of posting that information as a comment, I can live with it. I answered his comment and updated my answer accordingly.

Then another "sub-question" was added, which I also answered. And then comes another question ... so, basically, the comment section becomes a forum-style discussion.

I asked the OP to start a new question for any other problem that is not related to his original question. So far to no avail. I am thinking about just deleting my answer, just to put an end to that discussion. But, admittedly, that's a rather blunt thing to do.

This isn't the first time I encounter a situation like the one above. It's mostly people (relatively) new to SO.

So, generally speaking, is there a commonly accepted approach to deal with these situations here on SO? And, if yes, what is it?

**UPDATE**

Just found this related [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298108/how-to-explain-edit-your-question-instead-of-adding-to-comments-to-a-user).

Comment: that sounds like a mild (but still annoying) form of [chameleon question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253829/839601) (for the sake of completeness, hard / strongly abusive form is when asker does the same but instead of comments, edits the question)

Comment: Minor follow-up questions are OK, if they are trivial and/or closely related to your answer. People's tolerance to these things varies: if you find that swathes of time are being eaten up by an overly-long conversation, draw it to a close and invite the OP to ask a new question.

Comment: I don't know if I would have answered that question in the first place. It's a pretty bad question. This OP seems like someone who badly wants help on the internet, and got really excited as soon as he got someone "on the line" that he could talk to. Don't be a fish. You'll just get reeled in again! :)

Comment: Clarify in comments, if it's a substantively different question suggest asking properly. If they don't want to, you can always open a question yourself. Revert question edits if change the question core meaning (if there's answers anyway)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Walk away. If new questions keep on coming that stray away from the initial questions asked, just inform the OP that he should ask a new well phrased question. And from there on just step away from the current question.

If the comments really get out of hand you could flag for moderator attention. Use the "other" option and tell them that the comments are getting far too drawn out and you would like to see them cleaned up. But before that, make sure you're no longer engaging in the discussion yourself and that the comment length is actually problematic. (i.e. highly off-topic, no longer related to the question asked, etc.) I'd say the current comments are not there just yet.

But whatever you do, don't delete your answer. Keep in mind that you're not just answering for the OP, but for the wider audience of the internet as a whole.

Comment: @pnuts Agreed, and bravo for the correct use of the word "bemused" :)